# How to solve an integral with an exponential and function.

Tags: laplace-transform

How do I solve the integral $ \int \limits _0 ^t e^x y(x) \Bbb d x$?  I know the integral of $y(x)$ would result in $\frac {Y(s)} s$.

Comment: you know the laplace transform of y I assume?

Comment: I posted what the laplace transform of y is.  When integrating y(x) the answer is Y(s)/s.

Answer (score 0):

We can write that integral as

$$\int ^\infty _0 y(x)\big(u(x)-u(x-t)\big)e^{-sx}dx$$

Where $u(x)$ is the unit step function and $s=-1$. The laplace transform of a product, is the convolution of the laplace transforms.

$$Y(s)*\frac{1-e^{-st}}{s}\bigg|_{s=-1}=\int^\infty_{-\infty}Y(-1-s)\frac{1-e^{-st}}{s}ds$$

Nothing more can be said with the given information

Comment: How is convolution involved in this?

Comment: I multiply the integrand with a rectangle function.

Comment: I don't understand how you rewrote the integral though...

Comment: Rectangle function is zero in $[t,\infty]$ So I can pull the bounds of the integral to infinity to make it look like a laplace transform.